# Setup second static IP to server behind Netgear router?

Tags: router, static-ip

I have a WNR3500L Netgear router. Our ISP is Surewest, and they have provided us 5 static IP addresses (66.x.x.106/110). I have setup the router to use 66.x.x.106 as a static IP, and have setup the DHCP subnet to be 10.1.10.2/100.

I have a desktop I use for development on 10.1.10.123 (outside DHCP range). Is it possible to set it up so all traffic to/from 66.x.x.107 (second static IP) goes to 10.1.10.123?

I think the proper term is NAT 1:1, but I can't seem to find this anywhere in the interface. Closest thing is "Static Routes".

(Port forwarding alone isn't enough as we'll have a few machines that all need port 80 for web development testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people chose to replace the default operating system on routers like this with a more flexible, open version, like `dd-wrt` or `openwrt`. Here is an explanation for how to do it with dd-wrt for example:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/One-to-one_NAT

Find `dd-wrt` at: http://www.dd-wrt.com/
Find `openwrt` at: http://openwrt.org/

Good luck!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without third party firmware? I understand there is some risks involved if done incorrectly, especially with Netgear routers.

Comment: I don't think so, sadly. I have Netgear routers too but can't find an option unless I too miss something obvious. It should be fine to run dd-wrt on your router, just check the dd-wrt wiki and do as it says! And also prepare for how to back out of it if it locks up!

Comment: That's the thing... if I brick this I have to buy a $20 cable and take it apart. With other routers you don't have to do this. I was hoping "Static Routes" was what I was looking for. The safter route may be just to put a switch infront of the router. I could have sworn you could do this with the older Netgear routers.

Comment: "Static Routes" just have to do with IP routing and nothing to do with NAT, so unfortunatelly not what you are looking for. :( Sorry, can't help you then.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is introduce a consumer 5 port gig switch to your design.  Plug the switch to the public wire from surewest. then use another port on the switch to go to your NetGear router. This hosts your first IP address (the router does).  Now, take another port on the switch, and connect a wire to it, and the other end to the Computer that you want on the next Public IP you are assigned from Surewest. Configure the PC for the Public IP address #2 on your set of 5 addresses. All traffic will forward to that PC at that address.  Voila.

If you would prefer added security, put a second router on that switch, preceding the Computer.